# Is matrix $B$ an image of matrix $A?$

Tags: matrices, geometry, transformation

Consider the following two matrices:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}   e^s&0\\   0&e^{-s}   \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ B=\begin{pmatrix}   e^{e^s} &0\\   0&e^{e^{-s}}   \end{pmatrix} $$

Is $B$ an image of $A?$ If we let $e^s\leftrightarrow s$ then does this imply that $B$ is an image of $A?$ I'm a little confused about this.

Comment: What does it mean to say that a matrix is an image of another matrix?

Comment: I was thinking since $A$ defines a hyperbolic rotation, maybe $B$ would be an image of a hyperbolic rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B=e^A$, the matrix $B$ is the image of $A$ by the exponential map.